# retrieving 'pre windows 2000 logon' name from LDAPMessage object in win32api C++

Tags: c++, winapi, active-directory, ldap

I've been asked to look at windows service which retrieves data from an Active Directory tree using the win32 LDAP API and outputs JSON data to a text file. It works fine but I need to modify it so that the i get the 'pre windows 2000' login name. The service is written in c++.

The service already successfully retrieves various other attribute strings using:

```
PTSTR *pszValues=ldap_get_values(pLdap,pEntry,szAttribute);
```

and:

```
if (_tcscmp(szAttribute,TEXT("uUsnChanged"))==0)            // uSNChanged is an example of an attribute
pItemInfo->uUsnChanged=_tcstoui64(pszValues[0],NULL,10);    // pItemInfo is a struct defined elsewhere to hold the results for any given entry
```

i looked on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679021(v=VS.85).aspx to see if there is an attribute for 'pre windows 2000' login or something similar in the hope that I could just add this as another 'szAttribute' (to replace "uUsnChanged" in this example) and had no luck. Looking at the API i have been unable to come up with a way of getting this information.

i found the attribute 'sAMAccountName' which i thought would provide the information needed but it only gives me the **name** part of the **DOMAIN/name** format. Typical, it's the other part i want!

does anyone have any ideas on how to get the  **'pre windows 2000'** string from 'pEntry'?

@JPBlanc We are getting the correct nETBIOSName attribute now when running it on the test server. The app works on the assumption that there is a maximum of one nETBIOSName attribute per DC. It finds it by doing the following:

gets the default host using `ldap_init(NULL,0)`

get the 'configuration naming context' using `ldap_search_s(pLdap,NULL,LDAP_SCOPE_BASE,NULL,pszAttrs,FALSE,&pResults);` passing in the connection handle as the first parameter

retrieves the 'configurationNamingContext' attribute using `ldap_get_values(pLdap,pEntry,TEXT("configurationNamingContext"));`

concatenates "CN=Partitions," to the beggining of the string giving something like "CN=Partitions,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com,DC=au"

it then performs a search using `ldap_search_s(pLdap,szPartitionNC,LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE,TEXT("(nETBIOSName=*)"),pszAttrs,FALSE,&pResults);`

then it loops through the results looking for anything with a 'nETBIOSName' attribute and once it finds one it breaks out of the loop and returns the value.

Do you know if this is sufficient to work in any AD configuration?

Comment: Your edit 1) Completely changes your question, making my earlier answer irrelevant and 2) Is nonsensical -- if all you want is the `DOMAIN` part of `DOMAIN\name`, then you **must** already have it or you wouldn't be able to make an LDAP connection in the first place...

Comment: I was under the impression that the 'pre windows 2000 domain' could be different to the actual domain the active directory tree is on, it's with this in mind that I am attempting to get the pre windows 2000 domain name. I know very little about LDAP and have tried to glean as much as I can about the difference today. For example....

user logon name: user@something.somewhere.com.au...

User logon name (pre-Windows 2000): SOMETHING\user...

are you saying that the 'SOMETHING' in 'User logon name (pre-Windows 2000)' is neccessarily the same as the 'something' in the 'user logon name'?

Comment: No, the `SOMETHING` in `SOMETHING\user` is a netbios display name for a domain, and the `something.com.au` in `user@something.com.au` is a fully qualified domain name. But you need a domain name to connect to LDAP at all, at which point you either have the netbios name directly and used it to connect, or can trivially extract the netbios name from the fully qualified name with which you used to connect.

Comment: the application sits on the server itself and the connection is made using `ldap_init(NULL,0)` the NULL argument means that `ldap_init()` will look for the default DC and no domain name is needed. It is meant to just work without having to configure the domain name on installation.

Comment: Assuming your program **isn't** running on a domain controller, `ldap_init` is documented to "_search for a DC in the domain in which the current computer is a member when attempting to connect_". So it sounds like all you really want is the name of the domain in which the current computer is a member, no? This can be obtained by calling [`GetComputerNameEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724301(VS.85).aspx) with a first argument of `ComputerNameDnsDomain` or `ComputerNamePhysicalDnsDomain`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful, the Domain part of the 'pre windows 2000 domain' can be completly different from the user Principal Name (user@domain) use to logon onto Active-Directory. the DOMAIN is the Primary Domain Controleur name or the Netbios domain name. DOMAIN is created during domain creation, by default it's part of the DNS name, but it can be completly changed during domain creation.

You can find it with `nETBIOSName` attribute :

```
ldifde -f netbios.ldf -d "CN=Partitions,CN=Configuration,DC=your-DNS-Name" -r "(netbiosname=*)"
```

A best filter would be

```
(&(objectcategory=crossref)(dnsHostName=<DomainDNSName>)(netbiosname=*))
```

Comment: @ildjarn Thanks a lot for your comments. These, along with a couple of tips from other sources, have meant we've been able to solve the issue! It was more of a lack of understanding of the structure of Active Directory than the API that was hindering us, so thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

[SAM-Account-Name Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679635%28VS.85%29.aspx) (sAMAccountName)